# leftJoinWithCassandraTable using spark-cassandra-connector

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

How to implement leftJoinWithCassandraTable in cassandra, Using spark-cassandra-connector.I am using scala 2.11/DSE5.0.3/Spark 1.6.2.

I guess 2.0 has the methods in the RDDFunctions class. Please let me know your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked this [leftJoinWithCassandraTable](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.6.5/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/RDDFunctions.scala#L198)?

```
  /**
    * Uses the data from [[org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD RDD]] to left join with a Cassandra table without
    * retrieving the entire table.
    * Any RDD which can be used to saveToCassandra can be used to leftJoinWithCassandra as well as any
    * RDD which only specifies the partition Key of a Cassandra Table. This method executes single
    * partition requests against the Cassandra Table and accepts the functional modifiers that a
    * normal [[com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD]] takes.
    *
    * By default this method only uses the Partition Key for joining but any combination of columns
    * which are acceptable to C* can be used in the join. Specify columns using joinColumns as a parameter
    * or the on() method.
    *
    * Example With Prior Repartitioning: {{{
    * val source = sc.parallelize(keys).map(x => new KVRow(x))
    * val repart = source.repartitionByCassandraReplica(keyspace, tableName, 10)
    * val someCass = repart.leftJoinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, tableName)
    * }}}
    *
    * Example Joining on Clustering Columns: {{{
    * val source = sc.parallelize(keys).map(x => (x, x * 100))
    * val someCass = source.leftJoinWithCassandraTable(keyspace, wideTable).on(SomeColumns("key", "group"))
    * }}}
**/
```

Comment: This code is not available on the spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.2. Its available on spark-cassandra-connector 1.6.4 and upwards. I want 1.6.4 feature on 1.6.2.Any help much appreciated.

Comment: you could consider `partitioned` CassandraRDD and do `leftOuterJoin` with it. https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v1.6.2/doc/16_partitioning.md#joining-to-cassandra-rdds-from-non-cassandra-rdds